# How to set the value for dropdown array

Tags: javascript, jquery

image I have thinks like this here

```
<select id="brands[]" name="brands[]"><option value="121">...</option>...</select>
<select id="brands[]" name="brands[]"><option value="122">...</option>...</select>
<select id="brands[]" name="brands[]"><option value="123">...</option>...</select>
<select id="brands[]" name="brands[]"><option value="124">...</option>...</select>
 ...
```

Now I like to change the selected entry by value (not by index) for each of these boxes. I tried this here inside javascript tags:

```
$("#brands")[0].val('121'); 
$("#brands")[1].val('122');   
$("#brands")[2].val('123'); 
$("#brands")[3].val('124');
```

This does not works. Does any boy know how I can change the selected item by value for dropdownbox brands nr. x.

I have no more idea

Comment: IDs need to be unique.  You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.  Add a class, or select using the `name` attribute.  P.S. `$("#brands")[0]` won't return you a jQuery object.

Comment: Why do you have multiple selects? Seems like you're expecting there to be only one dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

**IDs must be unique**

However you can use `name`

```
var selects = $('select[name="brands[]"]')
selects.eq(0).val('121'); 
selects.eq(1).val('122');   
selects.eq(2).val('123'); 
selects.eq(3).val('124');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mdw9/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I gave each box an own id. Now I can change the value via its id. Thats works fine. Thanks alot